# Change the expand and collapse code to display on tablet and mobile only

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design

How to change the following expand collapse code to display on tablet and mobile only but not display on desktop? I need this for my responsive design. Is it possible? Or please suggest other code with this function for me. Thanks.

Desktop Design
[image]

Tablet/Mobile Design
[image]

```js
$(function() {
    $("#demo1 h3.expand").toggler();
    $("#demo2 h3.expand").toggler({initShow: "div.collapse:eq(0)"});

});
```

```css
* {margin:0; padding:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://staging.eimpressive.com/expand/jquery/expand.js"></script>


<div id="demo1" class="demo">
  <h3 class="expand">Title 1</h3>
  <div class="collapse shown">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
      et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
      ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
      eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa 
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <h3 class="expand">Title 2</h3>
  <div class="collapse">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
      et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
      ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
      eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa 
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to achieve this based on device or screen width?

Comment: yes. Currently I'm using @media only screen css code. I tried JavaScript resize --> `$(window).resize(function(){ if ($(window).width() <= 1049){ } });`, but not working. :(

Comment: You can use window.matchMedia(...) in javascript to get the same results as your CSS selectors.

Comment: Already tried but cannot works properly. The expand and collapse function affected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Media queries**

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

edia queries to include a max-width to limit CSS to a narrower set of devices.

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) and (max-width: @screen-md-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

Comment: This is used for css only right? Can you show me how to do? By using my code.